# Context.Handler conversion error

Tags: asp.net, type-conversion, httpcontext

Trying to do the following conversion:

```
CType(Context.Handler, MyCustomHandler)
```

But it is throwing following error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.MyWebForm_aspx' to type 'MyCustomHandler'.
```

Even both "Context.Handler" & "MyCustomHandler" are of type IHttpHandler.

***MyCustomHandler implements IHttpHandler.*

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of casting one handler to another unrelated handler type?  Even if the cast was possible, the new properties/methods exposed by `MyCustomHandler` would not be relevant to the instance of `ASP.MyWebForm_aspx`.

Comment: @mellamokb "MyCustomHandler" is being used to rewrite URLs. I need to call "Transfer" method on "MyCustomHandler" like CType(Context.Handler, MyCustomHandler).Transfter("~/AnotherPage.aspx"). Transfer method has logic to rewrite URL and transfer to another page using Server.Transfer("~AnotherPage.aspx"). Strange thing is does not throw error when website is publish on the server, but during debug it throws the conversion error.

Comment: just guessing, but can't you directly use the `HttpContext` handler?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be some more methods or properties in `Handler` than just what is exposed by the `IHttpHandler` interface. Try to cast to `IHttpHandler` this should work.

I don't think you can cast between two classes implementing an interface, as you can't cast between two classes derived from an abstract class, but you can cast both of them to the base class or interface

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of effort, resolve this issue. The conversion was legal, but the custom handler I registered was in  section compliant to IIS6 and older. Since I was running my website locally on IIS7 under Integrated mode, which looks registered handlers in  section under , and this handler wasn't registered there. There were two possible solutions:

1) Add custom handler in  section 
2) Change Integrated to Classic mode in II7

I went with 2nd one. 
**This also resolves the issue why it was working when I was publishing on server with IIS6 (Classic) and not locally (II7 with Integrated Mode)